# What's wrong in this dual derivation?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, duality-theorems, semidefinite-programming

I have a function in the form
\begin{align}
f(q,M)=\sup_{0\leq \alpha \leq 1} -\alpha^T (R\odot M)\alpha+\alpha^Tq
\end{align}
which is a dual of a minimization problem, 
where $R$ and $M$ are positive semidefinite matrices, and $\alpha$ and $q$ are vectors of length,$n$. Now I have a minimization problem, in the following form
\begin{align}
\text{minimize }_{q,M} &f(q,M)+\frac{1}{2} \Vert q \Vert^2\cr
\text{s.t.} & M \succeq q q^T
\end{align}
I compute the lagrangian of the problem,
\begin{align}
\mathsf{L}=f(q,M)+\frac{1}{2} \Vert q \Vert^2-tr(\begin{bmatrix} Z,z\\z^T,v\\  \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} M,q\\q^T,1\\  \end{bmatrix})
\end{align}
My question is how to derive $\frac{\partial}{\partial M}L$. Because when I want to derive it,I got the following, which is contradictory because $\alpha \alpha^T\odot R$ and $Z$ are positive semidefinite.
What is wrong?
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial M}L=-\alpha \alpha^T\odot R -Z = 0
\end{align}
I wrote the problem in this equivalent form,
\begin{align}
\text{minimize }_{t,q,M} &t+\frac{1}{2} \Vert q \Vert^2\cr
\text{s.t.} & M \succeq q q^T\cr
&t\geq -\alpha^T (R\odot M)\alpha+\alpha^Tq
\end{align}
Now, The lagrangian can be written for the above problem using standard techniques,
\begin{align}
\mathsf{L}(t,q,M;Z,z,v,u,w,s)&=t+\frac{1}{2} \Vert q \Vert^2-tr(\begin{bmatrix} Z,z\\z^T,v\\  \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} M,q\\q^T,1\\  \end{bmatrix})+u(-\alpha^T (R\odot M)\alpha+\alpha^Tq-t)\cr
&=(1-u)t+\frac{1}{2} \Vert q \Vert^2-tr((Z+u(R\odot \alpha\alpha^T))^TM)-2 z^T q -v+uq^T \alpha
\end{align}
Still the same problem exists.
Please notice that I want to know how to derive the dual correctly. The problem is feasible and bounded. But the above analysis suggest it's not. Also, a question similar to this but about a different problem asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1375602/if-this-problem-is-not-unbounded-whats-wrong-in-this-dual-derivation)

Comment: This is the form of the problem, because it is lenghty.

Comment: Your $f$ is a supremum, may be non-smooth. How come you got $\alpha$ in your derivative when $L$ does not depend on it after taking the supremum? By the way, is $\odot$ the Hadamard multiplication?

Comment: At first it was nested minimiziation in the form $\text{minimize}_{q,M} \text{minimize}_{\alpha}$. For some reasons, I have to first derive the dual of the inner minimization and after that derive dual of complete problem. I assumed for a single $\alpha$, in derivative of $\alpha$. I think this is wrong but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Assume the supremum in $f$ is attained at $\alpha_0$. It depends on $M$ and $q$, i.e. $\alpha_0(M,q)$, and you have to consider derivatives of $\alpha$ in $L$ too. However, $\alpha_0$ is unlikely to be differentiable (or even continuous) due to the hyper-cube constraints. I think that derivations leads nowhere here, it is non-smooth optimization.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\alpha=0$ is feasible and gives $-\alpha^T (R\odot M)\alpha+\alpha^Tq=0$ $\quad\Rightarrow\quad$ $f(q,M)\ge 0$ $\quad\Rightarrow\quad$ $g(q,M)=f(q,M)+\frac12\|q\|^2\ge 0$ $\quad\Rightarrow\quad$ $\min\, g(q,M)\ge 0$.

Now take $q=0$ $\quad\Rightarrow\quad$ $f(0,M)=0$ $\quad\Rightarrow\quad$ $g(0,M)=0$.

Conclusion: the minimum is *zero*, attained at $(0,M)$ for any positive semi-definite $M$.

Comment: He didn't ask for a solution, he asked for help deriving the dual.

Comment: Yes. Michael is right. I just need help in deriving the dual. I just didn't put all of the problem in the question because it's lengthy. As I mentioned in the problem it is only the form of the problem.

Comment: @MichaelGrant, Could you please help me in this question? In case there wasn't any minimization before the sup, I just convert it to a minimization by multiplying it by minus one and it seems things comes right. But In this case I don't know what to do?